# Cannot run Django heroku app locally on Windows

Tags: django, windows, python-3.x, virtualenv, heroku-toolbelt

So, I want to test my app locally, but something goes wrong.
After installing `virtualenv`, activating it, installing `requirements.txt` and running `collectstatic` I try to run app with

```
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

I get

```
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
```

And that's all. I wait for about 30 mins and then stop execution. Then I get

```
16:07:33 web.1   |  Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x042BEF60>
16:07:33 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Traceback is empty. This is all output. Sometimes, when I wait for about only 1-2 minutes no messages appear at all.

File `Procfile.windows` looks like:

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

What's wrong? Why this exception occurs?

Comment: Why are you stopping the server? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Can we see more code? Is it just a hello world application?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, because there's no point in waiting longer, as it should start within a few seconds.

Comment: @User, yes it is.

Comment: But still I don't understand what you are expecting to see on the console. Did you try actually accessing the local server? Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having the same issue; however, I noticed that the procfile command IS being run, but heroku is swallowing the console output. Which means if there is an error in the django code, the server silently does not start.

I can run manage.py runserver manually to see the console output, but that means having to configure the .env variables separately (which I'd rather not do, as I have multiple Heroku/Django apps locally).

However, for some reason, **if I save any project file (even with no changes) while the server is running, the console output starts to appear as expected**